# How do I lock a cell's copied value determined by a formula and prevent it from updating when the referenced cell in formula does?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, reference, copy, array-formulas

the sheet I'm working on generates a request number on the very first submission a user makes of a google form based off of information the user inputted in the form and a timestamp. Now, because I need for the user to be able to edit their response later which causes the form to be re-submitted, I want the request number not to be regenerated, and to stay the same as when it was initially generated. Is there any way to prevent a cell from changing from its initial value when it contains a formula that references a cell that updates?

Here is the formula contained in the cell I don't want to update with alongside its references:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(if(ROW(A:A)=1, "Request ID", if(D1:D="", "",C1:C&"-"&G1:G&"-"&N1:N)), MAX(if(D1:D="",0,ROW(D1:D)))-ROW()+1,1))
```

The formula appends different values received from the form together to create a request number (formatted as essentially C1:C-G1:G-N1:N, timestamp-System-initials) and the arrayformula and constraint ensures the formula is copied to each row in the sheet that contains a form response so far. I want this request number to stay the same as it's initial value, even as columns C, G, and N change.

Edit: Not really sure how I can provide a search history on what I've tried so far because I've been searching for anything I can to fix this problem because it's important. I've looked into indirect referencing, absolute references, considered using `PropertiesService` (Google Apps Script) in order to store whether the request number has been initiated before and got stuck there, considered copying the value into another column to store it but again the autoupdating feature that accompanies linking cells of course still remains an issue. I'm stuck on what kind of function/workaround I could use to achieve this. Look forward to your thoughts. I've also tried a number of other strategies as well.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since formulas recalculate each time the spreadsheet is recalculated using a formula is not the right way to keep the original value on the current spreadsheet version. The way to achieve this is by using a script to log those values.

There are already a lot of questions about using a script to log values from one sheet to another. Here are few examples

- [How to Get (& Set) cell values from one sheet to another in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49116651/1595451)
- [I want to write a script to read and log values of a specific row and copy them to a new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56990825/1595451)